# What does Vector3.Projection mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What does projection mean in unity?

I have the following codes but I don't know the concept of them can anybody help me and tell me what does these lines mean?

```
Vector3 normal = (end_line.position - start_line.position).normalized;
Vector3 pos = start_line.position + Vector3.Project (target.position-start_line.position,normal);
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the [relevant documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Project.html)?

Comment: Yes but Unfortunately i didn't get the concept

Answer (score 7):

```
Vector3 normal = (end_line.position - start_line.position).normalized;
```

`normal` is the direction of the line (vector). It is normalized so that its magnitude be equal to 1. If you remove the `.normalized` part it will represent the line (vector) itself.

Let's break this down:

```
Vector3 pos = start_line.position 
              + Vector3.Project(target.position - start_line.position, normal);
```

`target.position-start_line.position` is another vector which starts from `start_line` and ends at `target`

`Vector3.Project(target.position - start_line.position, normal)` projects this vector onto the `normal`.

If `normal` is the direction of a straight-lined river starting at `(0,0,0)`, `start_line.position` is the position of a boat on the river and `target.position` is where user wants the boat to go (could be outside of the river), then the resulting vector is the movement of the boat along the river.

If you move that vector equal to `start_line` you will get `pos` = final position of the boat.

*There is also `Vector3.ProjectOnPlane` in Unity which can be thought of as the shadow of an object projected onto the ground (pass the plane's normal instead of vector's normal).*

### What exactly is Vector3.Project

in `p = Vector3.Project(a,n)`

Simply; how much vector `a` is drawn along the direction of `n`.

`a` is the source vector which is being projected onto `n`.

`n` is a normalized vector and it can represent an axis. *I don't know if normalized vector (0,1) and not normalized vector (0,2) give same result or not.*

`p` is a vector created by projecting `a` onto `n`.

You can always assume that `n` starts from where `a` starts from. Since `n` is an axis you can assume that it is an endless line (from -inf to +inf). So if you move `a` to the zero point on `n` axis (starting point of `n` vector) you will have something like this:

[image]
*normal is (0,1,0)*

vector=a, onNormal=n, Projection=p

- if `a.normalized = n` then `p = a`.
- if `a is perpendicular to n` then `p = Vector3.zero`.
- `p.magnitude <= a.magnitude`